# How can i display 2 EditText data from array in one Activity in textview....?

Tags: java, android

When i display one textview it works, but when i display the second, the first textview disappears. Please help.

Here is my code

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String[] data = intent.getStringArrayExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);


    TextView name = new TextView(this);
    name.setTextSize(25);
    name.setText(data[0]+"\n");
    name.setText("\n"+data[1]);

    // Show text view

    setContentView(name);

/*  AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(DisplayMessageActivity.this).create();
    dialog.setTitle(name);
    dialog.setMessage(message);
*/  
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();
```

Comment: use name.setText(data[0]+"\n"+data[1])

Comment: Every time you call `name.setText()`, it will replace the previous text.

Comment: append the strings. you are setting text in one textview only. It is working correctly. It is just replacing the text.

Answer (score 0):

Its overwrite the value on TextView.

So Use:

```
name.setText(data[0]+"\n"+data[1]);
```

Instead Of:

```
name.setText(data[0]+"\n");
name.setText("\n"+data[1]);
```

U can also use :

```
String dataStr="";
for(int i=0;i<data.length();i++)
{
   dataStr=dataStr+"\n"+data[i];
}
name.setText(dataStr);
```

Comment: If my answer solved your issue then u can accept it as an Answer!!

Answer (score 0):

you must set text in one step

```
   name.setText(data[0]+"\n"+data[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not appending text to your textview. You are actually replacing the text in textview. Before you do name.setText(); just add name.getText().toString();

For example: name.setText(name.getText().toString()+" My New data ");

Though it would be a good practice if you can use a StringBuilder for this. But above code should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to display whole array to textview,Just convert the **array to string** and set as text

```
name .setText(Arrays.toString(array));
```